# Open another workbook when opening workbook #1

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to automatically open Excel workbook #2 when opening Excel workbook #1.

What I attempted was to edit the ThisWorkbook object in workbook #1 and add the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\odds_datalog.xlsm")
End Sub
```

Oddly, this opens workbook #2 correctly, but for workbook #1 all I see is a never ending green Excel splash screen.

Is there a workaround for this? Thanks.

I have MS Office 365.

Comment: Is there a workbook_open macro in workbook #2?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for a "workaround" why don't you just call a small batch in the opening event that in turn opens your workbook#2?

Do something like this in the opening event:

```
Dim strBatchName as String
strBatchName = "C:\SomeFile.bat"
Shell strBatchName
```

And something like this within the batch:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Excel.exe" "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\File1.XLS"
```

You won't even notice the batch - hope this helps
Cheers

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need to be able to share the worksheets and have them run on other people's systems.

Comment: Do you want workbook#2 to be opened in a new excel session? Then you might want to try to instantiate a new excel session: [1]Dim NewExcel As New Excel.Application [2]NewExcel.Workbooks.Open "your path" [3]NewExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True [4]NewExcel.Visible = True